# ACAccountStore accountsWithAccountType returning empty list yet request to access is granted

Tags: ios, swift, acaccountstore

I have the following piece of Swift code to connect to twitter account in my iOS simulator.

My call to `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` is granted, but the `ACAccountStore.accountsWithAccountType` returns an empty list.

What am I missing?

```
let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
let twitterAccountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)

accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(twitterAccountType, options: nil) { (granted, error) in
    if granted {
        print("requestAccessToAccountsWithType for \(twitterAccountType) is granted\n")
        let accounts = accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(twitterAccountType)
        print("accountsWithAccountType returns \(accounts.count) ")
    } else {
        let error = "Access to Twitter was not granted."
        self.log(error)
        handler(error)
    }
}
```

> requestAccessToAccountsWithType for Twitter (com.apple.twitter) is granted
>   accountsWithAccountType returns 0

Comment: Granting access is one thing, you would also need to have a Twitter account configured on the device/simulator. Check if you have any accounts set up.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow assume that it will use my twitter account settings on my Mac. I setup my account in the simulator and it's working now.

Comment: Cool, I added it as an answer, feel free to accept! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Granting access is one thing, you would also need to have a Twitter account configured on the device/simulator. Check if you have any accounts set up.

Comment: Should mention you actually have to go to the Settings app on the iOS simulator and add the account - just like in real life :) I was trying to add the account within Xcode.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, but you're right, it's clearer this way. :)